# How can I bind Ctrl-Space to be Esc when not in insert mode, and to switch to insert mode otherwise?

Tags: key-bindings, escape

I dislike to have to reach up to the `Escape` key all the time. For a while I used the program `xcape` under Linux to map `Caps lock` to be both `Control` and `Escape`. However, I am currently working more and more on a Mac so I can’t have the same keybinding without much increased effort.

I thought that the key combination of `Control`-`Space` would be quite nice.

I tried to rebind with:

```
map <NUL> <ESC>
nmap <NUL> i
```

But that does not work correctly, often inserting the same text again.

Comment: An alternative to `Esc` key that is more 'reachable' is `Ctrl-[`

Comment: Why would <Nul> be a ctrl-space?

Comment: Control-Space is a potentially difficult thing, since it's a signal which differnt TERMs send differently. It can be <C-Space> or <NUL>, if it's sent at all.

Answer (score 12):

I found this map works for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> :

```
:nnoremap <C-@> i
:inoremap <C-@> <Esc>
```

Comment: Yes, I found that's what I have had to use for `vim` in terminals. The way to discover such things is to see what Vim produces when you type `i<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-Space>` or `:<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-Space>`.

Comment: Beware if you use Ubuntu 14.04, iBus may be intercepting the keystroke. Check the preferences of the little keyboard icon in the dock that lets you select language / keyboard input method, and change the mapping to something else (I went for `<Ctrl-Alt-Space>`).

Answer (score 6):

```
nnoremap <C-Space> i
inoremap <C-Space> <Esc>
```

Comment: Does not do anything in normal mode exept beeping and in insert mode somehow triggers completion. :/

Comment: Do you have existing mappings for c-space? These should work, I think, unless your vim is not recognizing the keystroke.

Comment: Should work for most modern terminals, however you can also map `<C-@>`like @tivn suggests, that works as well, the reason being both send the same key codes to vim.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the touch bar escape key is a bit difficult to hit reliably, Mac now has an option to turn capslock into the escape key.  System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys.

Comment: I believe that option existed before the touch bar, but I could be wrong. At any rate, welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

As @pdr written, macOS has the ability to change the behavior of some modifier keys.

You can go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` and check on the lower right corner of the window. There is the button `Modifier keys...`.

If you click the `Modifier keys...` button, then a drop-down panel appears when you can change the behavior of the keys:

- Capslock
- Control
- Option
- Command
- Function

Personally, I have mapped `Capslock` to `Escape`.

This works also in the touch-bar models of Apple.