# Rebinding i (enter insert mode) and Esc (enter normal mode) to Ctrl-Space

Tags: key-bindings, original-vim

`Esc` doesn't work for me for obvious reasons. So I started using `C-c` but I'm told that's bad practice. In addition it isn't as convenient as I like it to be.

So I looked into binding `C-Space` and found [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/how-can-i-bind-ctrl-space-to-be-esc-when-not-in-insert-mode-and-to-switch-to-in) which toggles between insert and normal mode.

```
:nnoremap <C-@> i
:inoremap <C-@> <Esc>
```

I guess I can extend this to exiting other modes like `visual` to `normal` by using `:vnoremap`, etc.

This is perfect. The only problem I face is that when pressing `C-Space` in insert mode to switch to normal mode, the caret moves back by one position. That's quite annoying.

I also tried the `nnoremap <C-Space> i` version but that doesn't work on my system. I'm on an Ubuntu Focal. I read some comment that Ubuntu 14 captures that sequence or some such.

Terminal: Konsole
WM: i3

I have also GNOME and KDE Plasma from when I used them.

Comment: What exactly is the question? If it’s just the cursor movement, that’s what happens when you escape (it makes sense at the end of a line, or if you consider that in normal mode your cursor is on a character, whereas in insert mode it is on the space between characters, where it will be inserting.)

Comment: You are right. This movement is normal. I was probably confused and doubted my original bindings. It's my first time doing such things. Going to remove the post as it makes no sense and will probably only confuse less experienced people like myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `l` to the end of your existing imap.  This will move the cursor to the right by one position.

You might see a difference with column 1 though.  I control this with an expression in a remap.

```
inoremap <expr> jk (col('.')==1 ? '<esc>' : '<esc>l')
```